# Laravel - Is it possible to access controller function in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet

so I have this one table in view where all the columns and rows are displaying a mathematical calculation. Every calculation were calculated in controller which is not store in the database.

The problem is I need to do an excel export based on the table display in view. I'm using phpspreadsheet and I'm writing the code in eloquent. I want to get all the variable in the controller and display in the excel code in my eloquent. Is it possible to do that?

Fyi, the controller with all the mathematical code was coded by previous developer, I was asked to added export excel function only which I'm not sure how to get all the method inside the controller.

I already did the export excel but only on getting all data that exist in the database which is easier because all I need is `query = Model::all();`

Comment: You can move the controller stuff to a static method on the model, then call that from the controller or move them to mutations. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Use https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel. Create File named CustomExport.php and copy your logic from controller. And call CustomExport anywhere in application.

Comment: @MichaelMano As I'm still new in laravel, do you mind to explain on how can I move it to static method in model?

Comment: @user16803568 show us the code and I can, or at least some of the magic going on in the controller.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code you are talking about, Here is what I mean by moving the calculation and modification of the data from the controller to a static method in the model.

SomeController.php original:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $table_data = collect(SomeModel::all())->map(function($item) {
            // your funky table data stuff.
            return $item;
        })->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
            // your funky table data stuff.
            return $carry + $item;
        });

        return view('some-table-view', $table_data);
    }
}
```

Move the logic from your controller to the Model.

SomeModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SomeModel extends Model
{
    ...

    public static function tableData()
    {
        return collect(self::all())->map(function($item) {
            // your funky table data stuff.
            return $item;
        })->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
            // your funky table data stuff.
            return $carry + $item;
        });
    }
}
```

Your new SomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $table_data = SomeModel::tableData();
        return view('some-table-view', $table_data);
    }
}
```

Now you can call `SomeModel::tableData();` where its required.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use datatable with serverside false
[datatable with export button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.